# Can I use Ioc pattern to achieve the following goal

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container, spring.net, castle

I have two classes implemented the same static methods like the following,

```
Class A
{
  static OpB(); 
}

Class B
{
  static OpB();
}
```

Can I use Ioc pattern to switch ClassA and ClassB using the configuration?
Or any workaround or suggestions?

Comment: You cannot switch classes with static methods. Make them instance related and get both classes to be derived from the same interface or class. In case method names are and parameters the same you may use reflection to call static methods of different classes based on some configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IoC pattern pretty much prohibits you from using static methods because it focuses on *creating instances* of a type (service). Static methods are not instance methods, so an IoC container would give you an instance but you can't call a static method on an instance.

If it's possible to drop the static qualifier on the OpB() method you'll be able to do what you want using IoC.

Comment: If changing the existing code is not an option, you could create a wrapper around the existing class.